# How can I make sure that rsync deletes files AFTER the sync?

Tags: rsync

I want to sync files from location a to location b with rsync. Let's assume A and B are in sync. When now a file is deleted and some are changed, I want FIRST to sync all changed files to B and then process the delete(s). Here is what I have right now:

```
rsync -a --log-file=/tmp/rsync.log --stats --append-verify --partial \
--exclude=**/*tmp*/ --exclude=**/*cache*/ --exclude=**/*Cache*/ --exclude=**~ \
--exclude=**/*Trash*/ --exclude=**/*trash*/ --include=home/ --exclude=*  \
-e "ssh -y -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -p 22" / admin@10.0.0.1:/volume1/backup/
```

Comment: `--delete-after`? You probably ought to read the manual page for `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

I have over seen it. Thanks the `--delete-after`option does the trick!